# Верно ли, что метка [ruby-on-rails] исключает [ruby]?

Tags: обсуждение, использование-метки

Не раз видел, что в вопросе есть метка [ruby-on-rails](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), но нет метки [ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby). Всего про [ruby-on-rails](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) есть [358 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails). Из них [232 вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails+-ruby) не имеют метки [ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby).

Бывает, что эта метка добавлена автором, но её удаляет редактор, например вот [в этой правке, подтвержденной двумя опытными участниками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/56321).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание [ruby-on-rails](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) ничего не говорит о том, что эта метка исключает [ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby). Никаких логичных объяснений этому я тоже не могу найти. Разве для использования фреймворка не нужно использовать сам язык?

Почему так делают? Как правильно?

Comment: Похоже, ответ есть тут. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/info

Comment: Использовать язык нужно. Но, зачастую, вопросы, в которых стоят метки `Ruby` и `Ruby on Rails` касаются только последнего.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr** метку [ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) лучше употреблять **совместно** с меткой [ruby-on-rails](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), если нет уверенности, что вопрос касается только Ruby или только Rails. Проблема в том, что задающий вопрос часто не в состоянии определить, к каким меткам лучше отнести вопрос.

Особенно плоха ситуация с **ActiveSupport** (частью Rails, коллекцией расширений для стандартной библиотеки Ruby). Новички, изучая Ruby on Rails, быстро теряются, "где кончается Ruby, а где начинается Rails".

---

#### Теперь подробнее и сначала:

## Нет, не исключает.

Разумеется, Rails состоит из довольно большого количества компонентов, *не все из которых предполагают работу с кодом на Ruby*:

- Использование "конвейера ассетов" (asset pipeline) в лице Sprockets

  - За исключением необходимости написать для него расширение, что практически никогда в вопросах не поднимается, т. к. не относится к **использованию**.
- Написание запросов к БД

  - Это на грани, синтаксис запросов ActiveRecord основан на Ruby, но это форма, а не суть. Например, вопрос может касаться семантики методов из ActiveRecord (что про Rails), может касаться ассоциаций (Rails), а может касаться "ленивых вычислений" (что уже про Ruby) или присваивания в переменные частей запроса (тоже про Ruby). Автор вопроса по этой теме может быть слабо знаком с языковыми средствами, и потому не может знать наверняка, ставить тег [ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) или нет.
- Администрирование сервера с приложением на Ruby on Rails
- Шаблонизаторы, которые могут иметь собственный синтаксис

---

...но многие из средств, используемых в приложениях на Rails по умолчанию, не привязаны к фреймворку и могут применяться **отдельно** в любом проекте на Ruby (и не только).

- Гемы.
- Bundler (и связанный с ним Gemfile)
- Языки для генерации HTML/CSS/JS: CoffeeScript, HAML, ERB

---

Знать Ruby и правда необязательно, чтобы **начать** работать с Rails. Но при малейших отклонениях от конвенций и правил Rails придётся изучать, как всё это складывается внутри, для чего с большой вероятностью потребуется понимание Ruby. **Не каждую проблему можно решить, кинув в неё гемом,** *иногда* (сарказм) для решения проблемы необходимо написать собственную логику.

Comment: Спасибо, примерно понял, в чём тут дело.