# Стоит ли добавлять "глобальные" метки?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, модерация

Один из вариантов отклонить добавление метки к вопросу:

> Правка содержит новые метки, которые не помогают определить тему вопроса. Метки должны упрощать понимание того, о чём вопрос, а не только то, что он содержит.

Данная причина отклонения была использована для отклонения "общей" метки [haskell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell).

Лично я использую метки для фильтрации сообщений. Например, игнорирую все вопросы [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), [haskell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell).

Удобнее добавлять соответствующую "глобальную" метку к вопросу, а не добавлять в фильтр все `.net-фреймворк`.

Как принято редактировать метки? Добавлять только если они помогают определить тему, или стоит добавлять "глобальные" метки?

Comment: Кстати, также очень интересно, что делать с меткой [tag:ruby] в вопросах о [tag:ruby-on-rails].

Comment: Да я вообще не понимаю, при чём тут haskel. Ты уверен, что он там к месту?

Comment: @Qwertiy На сколько я понимаю, `haskell-stack` - какая-то "хрень" для сборки проектов `haskell`, я предположил, что они имеют непосредственное отношение друг к другу. Поэтому решил добавить метку к вопросу, а не в фильтр. Но мой вопрос касается не конкретного случая, а общих правил установки меток. Дальше мне как действовать? Ставить метки, или нет?

Comment: Да, проблема с добавлением меток есть. Всегда колеблюсь, добавлять ли, например, метки html, c# к вопросам по asp.net, когда приведён код страницы razor.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Верно ли, что метка \[ruby-on-rails\] исключает \[ruby\]?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2385/%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-ruby-on-rails-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

> Удобнее добавлять соответствующую "глобальную" метку к вопросу, а не добавлять в фильтр все .net-фреймворк.

Смотря какие именно метки. Если речь о версионных метках, то да, если на вопросе стоит, скажем, только метка [.net-4.5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.5), имеет смысл сделать правку и добавить метку [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), так как глобальную метку отслеживает большее число отвечающих. Но когда идет речь о различных продуктах, относящихся к .NET, следует быть внимательнее:

- [.net-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) - не подмножество [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) (.NET Framework), а отдельная реализация CLI. Добавлять метку [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) на вопрос с меткой [.net-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) будет неправильно, если только вопрос не о сравнении этих двух продуктов.
- [asp.net-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) - не подмножество [.net-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core), а отдельный фреймворк, который может использоваться как с .NET Framework, так и с .NET Core. Не следует самостоятельно добавлять метку правкой, но можно в комментариях попросить автора уточнить, что он использует.
- С другой стороны, ADO.NET - подмножество .NET Framework, и, если на вопросе только метка [ado.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ado.net), имеет смысл добавить метку [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), аналогично, чтобы вопрос могли увидеть больше отвечающих.

Словом, такие правки следует делать, только если разбираетесь в теме. Если цель - игнорировать все связанное с .NET, можно просто добавить в игнор `[*.net*]`, так как игнор поддерживает подстановочные знаки.